# Should I use the first and/or last slash in commands in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

What is the canonical way of using trailing and first slashes in Linux OS?

Which of these commands are the most canonical and preferred and unambiguous one should use in tutorials and script that are public?:

Let's say we want to tell the reader of our article to go into the "etc" folder in Ubuntu. What should we write as the command?

Here are the options I can think of:

1. cd etc
2. cd /etc
3. cd etc/
4. cd /etc/

So, which one is the less ambiguous and preferred way of telling that to our readers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if there is a canonical version, but these are different commands:

1. `cd etc` <-- change directory to 'etc' only if 'etc' exists in the current working directory
2. `cd /etc` <-- change directory to the 'etc' directory in the root of the file system
3. `cd etc/` <-- same as item 1. The trailing forward-slash makes it clear that this is a directory, but this isn't necessary since the 'cd' command provides ample context
4. `cd /etc/` <-- same as item 2. The trailing forward-slash makes it clear that this is a directory, but this isn't necessary since the 'cd' command and leading forward slash provide ample context

As far as the trailing forward-slash goes, I don't think it's necessary unless you need to indicate that something is a directory when it's otherwise unclear. In most cases it's not necessary and looks awkward. As long as you're communicating what a command is/does, extra details aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and download then study its [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) (since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [chdir(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html), [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

`cd etc`  or `cd etc/` are changing the current directory (of your `bash` [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) to the `etc` directory in the *current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)*.

`cd /etc` or `cd /etc/` are changing the current directory (of your shell) to the `/etc` directory in the [*root directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) . See [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), the [stat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) and [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) commands, the [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call.

You could prefer in your documentation, for readability, `cd /etc/` or `cd etc/` to remind your reader that `/etc/` is an existing directory.

Notice the existence of the [chroot(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) system call (used by the [chroot(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html) command) which could change the *root directory* (of your shell process). It is unusual to do so, and that [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) can fail (like many others, see [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)...). In rare cases, you would use the [chroot(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html) command.

Also, consider changing your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) with the [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) command. I prefer [zsh](https://zsh.org/) (see file `/etc/shells` documented in [shells(5))](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html). You could try the [`es` shell](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/).